# Android : Custom ArrayAdapter showContextMenu onClick

Tags: android, onclick

In my Android application I have a custom ArrayAdapter for managing rows in a List that implements onCLickListener.

In the onClick() method I want to show the context menu.

```
     public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> implements
                                                                OnClickListener  {

    public void onClick(View v) {

            v.showContextMenu();
    } 
}
```

In my main List Activity class I override the onLongListItemClick() method that starts a different Activity.

When I click on a row in the list - the context menu is shown correctly but a second later the onLongListItemClick() is also executed. How to stop this happening?

thanks!

Comment: Can't you reverse them?  Use the long click for the context menu (as normal) and a regular click to lauch the new activity.

Comment: in this case i need the long click to bring up an edit screen where the user can amend their original details and save. i have a checkbox beside each element in the list. so when the user clicks on the check box i want to bring up the context menu to give the 'delete' and 'edit options'

Comment: I don't understand, why can't that be part of the context menu?  I mean a choice in the menu...  or is it just that you want to eliminate that extra click of having to slect the menu item to edit?

Comment: exactly, i could remove the long click and just allow the edit to happen once the context menu option is selected. but i wanted to allow it at long click and in the context menu

Answer (score 0):

After your comments, I think I have a solution.  Don't use the row `onClick` for the context menu, set a click listener in your adapter for the checkbox and show your context menu from there.  That way you avoid the `onLongListItemClick`.

To make both the checkbox *and* the row clickable, add this to the checkbox definition in your XML:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

**EDIT**

This should do the trick:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) { 
        if(isChecked){
           View v = buttonView.getParent();  // get the parent row view containing the checkbox
           v.showContextMenu();     // show the context menu
        }
   } 
}
```

Comment: what would the click listener method look like?